# iframe vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, iframe, scrollbar

How do I get rid of the vertical scroll bar in the iframe?  See here:

http://lambodhara.tumblr.com/

The code is:

```
<iframe width="560" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://zleek.com/champ1979/navarathri-2009?embed=true&page=0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite perfect, but you could add an `overflow: hidden` to the Silverlight container in your iframe:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="overflow: hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

maybe?